# creating controller keeps model from getting to template

Tags: ember.js

I'm building my first ember app (ember-cli), and am confused.

I have the following route, which successfully chooses a view based on an attribute in the model:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  afterModel: function(tournament) {
    var state = tournament.get('state');
    if (state === 0) {
      this.transitionTo('tournaments.setup', tournament);
    } else if (state === 1) {
      this.transitionTo('tournaments.play', tournament);
    } else if (state === 2) {
      this.transitionTo('tournaments.complete', tournament);
    }
  }

});
```

Then I wanted to add some functionality to the `tournaments.setup` page. So I added a controller (at `tournaments/controllers/setup.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    start: function() {
      var that = this;
      var model = this.get('model');
      model.set('state',1);
      model.save().then(function(tournament) {
        that.transitionToRoute('tournaments.play', tournament);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

This worked, in the sense of enabling the `start` action that I had created to change the model and redirect to the desired route. But this also had the effect of keeping the model from making it to the `setup.hbs` template, shown below:

```
<h3>{{name}}</h3>
<h4>Setup!</h4>
<p>{{state}}</p>
<p>{{eventDate}}</p>
<button {{action "start"}} class="btn btn-primary">Start</button>
```

The attributes of the model are shown if the `controllers/tournaments/setup.js` file does not exist. Somehow creating this file, which is not called when I go to the `setup` route, prevents the model from reaching the template.

I've also tried explicitly defining the route `setup.js` route, but that didn't help.

I'm using the FixtureAdapter, if that matters. Any ideas? Is there a concept I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the model to be automatically set on your controller, you should extend `Ember.ObjectController` instead of `Ember.Controller` in `tournaments/controllers/setup.js`.

Comment: Answered, and tested successfully before the 15 minute accept-freeze expired!